# Message not delivered from firebase to device

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

Below is the tutorial which I am following (up till the part before PHP):-
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Config:

```
public class Config {
    //global topic to receive app wide push notifications
    public static final String TOPIC_GLOBAL = "global";

    //broadcast receiver intent filters
    public static final String REGISTRATION_COMPLETE = "registrationComplete";
    public static final String PUSH_NOTIFICATION = "pushNotification";

    //id to handle the notification in the notification tray
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 100;
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID_BIG_IMAGE = 101;

    public static final String SHARED_PREF = "ah_firebase";
}
```

MyFirebaseInstanceIDService

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    private static final String TAG = MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh(){
        super.onTokenRefresh();
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        //Saving reg id to shared pref
        storeRegIdInPref(refreshedToken);
        //Sending reg id to server
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
        //Notify UI that registration is completed so the progress indicator can be hidden
        Intent registrationComplete = new Intent(Config.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE);
        registrationComplete.putExtra("token",refreshedToken);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(registrationComplete);
    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(final String token){
        //sending GCM  token to server
        Log.e(TAG,"send RegistrationToServer: " + token);
    }

    private void storeRegIdInPref(String token){
        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putString("regId", token);
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

MyFirebaseMessagingService:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = MyFirebaseMessagingService.class.getSimpleName();
    private NotificationUtils notificationUtils;

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage){
        Log.e(TAG,"FROM: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        //Check if message contains a notification payload
        if(remoteMessage == null){
            return;
        }
        //check if message contains a data payload
        if(remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0){
            Log.e(TAG,"Data Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());
            try{
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().toString());
                handleDataMessage(json);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e(TAG,"Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    private void handleNotification(String message) {
        if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
            // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
            Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
            pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

            // play notification sound
            NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
            notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();
        }else{
            // If the app is in background, firebase itself handles the notification
        }
    }

    private void handleDataMessage(JSONObject json) {
        Log.e(TAG, "push json: " + json.toString());

        try {
            JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");

            String title = data.getString("title");
            String message = data.getString("message");
            boolean isBackground = data.getBoolean("is_background");
            String imageUrl = data.getString("image");
            String timestamp = data.getString("timestamp");
            JSONObject payload = data.getJSONObject("payload");

            Log.e(TAG, "title: " + title);
            Log.e(TAG, "message: " + message);
            Log.e(TAG, "isBackground: " + isBackground);
            Log.e(TAG, "payload: " + payload.toString());
            Log.e(TAG, "imageUrl: " + imageUrl);
            Log.e(TAG, "timestamp: " + timestamp);


            if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
                // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
                Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
                pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

                // play notification sound
                NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
                notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();
            } else {
                // app is in background, show the notification in notification tray
                Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                resultIntent.putExtra("message", message);

                // check for image attachment
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(imageUrl)) {
                    showNotificationMessage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, timestamp, resultIntent);
                } else {
                    // image is present, show notification with image
                    showNotificationMessageWithBigImage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, timestamp, resultIntent, imageUrl);
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Json Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Showing notification with text only
     */
    private void showNotificationMessage(Context context, String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent) {
        notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent);
    }

    /**
     * Showing notification with text and image
     */
    private void showNotificationMessageWithBigImage(Context context, String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent, String imageUrl) {
        notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent, imageUrl);
    }

}
```

NotificationUtils:

```
public class NotificationUtils {
    private static String TAG = NotificationUtils.class.getSimpleName();
    private Context mContext;
    public NotificationUtils(Context mContext){
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }
    public void showNotificationMessage(String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent){
        showNotificationMessage(title,message,timeStamp,intent,null);
    }
    public void showNotificationMessage(final String title, final String message, final String timeStamp,Intent intent,
                                        String imageUrl){
        //Check for empty push message
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(message)){
            return;
        }

        //notification icon
        final int icon = R.mipmap.ic_launcher;

        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        final PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                mContext,
                0,
                intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
        );

        final NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext);
        final Uri alarmSound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + mContext.getPackageName()
                +"/raw/notification");
        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(imageUrl)){
            if(imageUrl != null && imageUrl.length() > 4 && Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(imageUrl).matches()){
                Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromURL(imageUrl);
                if(bitmap != null){
                    showBigNotification(bitmap,mBuilder,icon,title,message,timeStamp,resultPendingIntent,alarmSound);
                }else{
                    showSmallNotification(mBuilder,icon,title,message,timeStamp,resultPendingIntent,alarmSound);
                }
            }
        }else{
            showSmallNotification(mBuilder,icon,title,message,timeStamp,resultPendingIntent,alarmSound);
            playNotificationSound();
        }

    }

    private void showSmallNotification(NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder,int icon,String title,String message,String timeStamp,
                                       PendingIntent resultPendingIntent,Uri alarmSound){
        NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
        inboxStyle.addLine(message);
        Notification notification;
        notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                .setSound(alarmSound)
                .setStyle(inboxStyle)
                .setWhen(getTimeMilliSec(timeStamp))
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), icon))
                .setContentText(message)
                .build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(Config.NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    }

    private void showBigNotification(Bitmap bitmap, NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder, int icon, String title, String message, String timeStamp, PendingIntent resultPendingIntent, Uri alarmSound) {
        NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle bigPictureStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();
        bigPictureStyle.setBigContentTitle(title);
        bigPictureStyle.setSummaryText(Html.fromHtml(message).toString());
        bigPictureStyle.bigPicture(bitmap);
        Notification notification;
        notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                .setSound(alarmSound)
                .setStyle(bigPictureStyle)
                .setWhen(getTimeMilliSec(timeStamp))
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), icon))
                .setContentText(message)
                .build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(Config.NOTIFICATION_ID_BIG_IMAGE, notification);
    }

    /**
     * Downloading push notification image before displaying it in
     * the notification tray
     */
    public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String strURL) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(strURL);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Playing notification sound
    public void playNotificationSound() {
        try {
            Uri alarmSound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE
                    + "://" + mContext.getPackageName() + "/raw/notification");
            Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(mContext, alarmSound);
            r.play();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method checks if the app is in background or not
     */
    public static boolean isAppIsInBackground(Context context) {
        boolean isInBackground = true;
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
            List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
            for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : runningProcesses) {
                if (processInfo.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
                    for (String activeProcess : processInfo.pkgList) {
                        if (activeProcess.equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                            isInBackground = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
            ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
            if (componentInfo.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                isInBackground = false;
            }
        }

        return isInBackground;
    }

    // Clears notification tray messages
    public static void clearNotifications(Context context) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.cancelAll();
    }

    public static long getTimeMilliSec(String timeStamp) {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        try {
            Date date = format.parse(timeStamp);
            return date.getTime();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private BroadcastReceiver mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver;

//for firebase
        mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                if(intent.getAction().equals(Config.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE)){
                    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(Config.TOPIC_GLOBAL);
                    displayFirebaseRegId();
                }else if(intent.getAction().equals(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION)){
                    String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
                    System.out.println("Message is: " + message);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Push Notification: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        };
        displayFirebaseRegId();

 private void displayFirebaseRegId() {
        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF, 0);
        String regId = pref.getString("regId", null);

        Log.e(TAG, "Firebase reg id: " + regId);

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(regId))
            System.out.println("Firebase Reg Id: " + regId);
        else
            System.out.println("Firebase Reg Id is not received yet!");
    }

    //for firebase
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // register GCM registration complete receiver
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(Config.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE));

        // register new push message receiver
        // by doing this, the activity will be notified each time a new message arrives
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION));

        // clear the notification area when the app is opened
        NotificationUtils.clearNotifications(getApplicationContext());
    }

    //for firebase
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver);
        super.onPause();
    }
```

Manifest (all within application tag):

```
<service android:name=".service.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service android:name=".service.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

There isn't any error during compilation. I am able to retrieve the `RegId`. From the firebase console, I am able to send the message and the status shows completed. However, I am unable to receive the notification in the device.

Comment: the manifest and json config is correct?

Comment: @EliasFazel sorry i missed out few lines from the tutorial >>  if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            handleNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

It's working now